# Having to run Webpack every time typescript file modified

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack along side with webpack-dev-server I am using something such as:

`"scripts": {
   "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --open --watch"
},`

I am using tsc --watch where my .tsx is located but, everytime I reload the files after a change I see no change. If I run /node_modules/.bin/webpack I then see my changes. Is there a way to tie this into webpack-dev-server?

Comment: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader

Comment: already using as my loader in my webpack.config.js  `module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },`

Comment: Then you don't need `tsc --watch` anymore, it will recompile typescript everytime it changes